# React - TypeScript destructuring of props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, destructuring

I have a function:

```
 export function getSubjectsForStudent(data: any) : any[]
```

"data argument" I receive from external source and it's not feasible to define strong type.
"return"  is derived from "data" so it's of type any as well.

A "Main" component passes "return" to a "child" component like this:

```
<MainCategories subjects={getSubjectsForStudent(data)} />
```

And in MainCategories

```
export default function MainCategories(props: any) {
    const tmp = props.subjects;
    ...
```

It works and it's Ok.

But I want
export default function MainCategories( **{subjects}** ) {

Can anybody help with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I often use this pattern to do that, but the main point is to define the props.

```
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

interface Props {
  // In your case
  subjects: any
}

const MainCategories: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({subjects}) => (
  ...
);

export default MainCategories;
```

Comment: This looks nice but what if you have several members defined on the `Props` and then you duplicate the same names in the destructuring object of the function parameters? You'd end up with code duplication...

Answer (score 11):

You need to add a type/interface of Props -
Then you'll be able to get subjects by destructuring.

```
interface Props {
  subjects: any
}

export default function MainCategories({ subjects }: Props) {
    const tmp = props.subjects;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

All other answers use an external `interface` declaration, which is a good practice. But for everyone looking for an one-liner destructuring, here it goes:

```
function Foo({name}: {name: string}) {
    return <div>{name}</div>;
}
```